# the playsound module is giving this unexpected error in python

Tags: python, timer, playsound

I am trying to make an code in python that let's you play musical chair,for this I need to make the code in such a way that I can start a timer as well as play a music at the same time so I am using this playsound module but it gives me this unexpected error:

```
    Error 263 for command:
        open "F:\My_codes\python\Dbot\dependencies\songs"        
    The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.

    Error 305 for command:
        close "F:\My_codes\python\Dbot\dependencies\songs"
    Cannot specify extra characters after a string enclosed in quotation marks.
Failed to close the file: "F:\My_codes\python\Dbot\dependencies\songs"
Exception in thread Thread-1 (play_sound):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "f:\My_codes\python\musical_chair.py", line 19, in play_sound
    playsound.playsound(song_path)
  File "C:\python310\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 72, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand(u'open {}'.format(sound))
  File "C:\python310\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 64, in winCommand
    raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException: 
    Error 263 for command:
        open "F:\My_codes\python\Dbot\dependencies\songs"
    The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.
```

and here is the code btw:

```
import time 
import playsound 
from threading import Thread
import random


def musical_chair(players):
    start_time = time.time()
    directory = "F"
    song_path = f"{directory}:\\My_codes\\python\\Dbot\\dependencies\\songs"
    

    seconds = ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60']

    time_played="".join(random.sample(seconds,1))
    print(time_played)

    def play_sound(): 
        playsound.playsound(song_path)

    t=Thread(target=play_sound)
    t.daemon=True
    t.start()

    while (time.time()-start_time)<int(5):         
        # print("running....")
        pass
musical_chair(2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
from playsound import playsound  # go to online .mp3 to wav converter 

playsound("C:\\Users\\ANURAG\\Music\\play.wav")
```